# Retrieve device token from device using ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am using `ionic` to develop an application and I need to get the device token for push notifications, but having trouble.  The application isn't receiving notifications, but I still need to send device token when user login into the application (e.g. I need to get device token without receiving notifications). I tried using the Cordova push notification plugin also.

Comment: Where is the code you have tried. and why you have pasted the exact thing three times?

Comment: thank you for correction mJunaidSalaat

Comment: I don't have any notification yet just i need to send device token when user login into the application that sit.i need to get device token with out any notification

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) plugin and its pretty easy and simple. For `regID` in the code on `deviceReady` event I've used.

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "SENDER-ID"
        },
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
        "windows": {} 
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log("registration event");
        //here is your registration id
        console.log(data.registrationId);
    });
```

[This](http://phonegappro.com/tutorials/apache-cordova-phonegap-push-notification-tutorial-part-1/) is the link of the tutorial too

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its nothing.. Just replace it with your sender id.

Comment: every time it returns different value i think device token is unique for device am i right

Comment: Watch out for issue in xcode https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/650#issuecomment-248598560

Comment: not working on with ionic v3  error:  Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Push'.ts(2339

Comment: @SayedMohdAli This is for Ionic v1 only. as it is ngcordova.

Comment: @junaid ok thanks, i think I have to do with FCM in ionic v3

Comment: the link to the tutorial seems to have a problem!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [ng-Cordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) document which is for getting current device token id.

copy and past it in your project controller.

In the given below line you can find **notification** parameter

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification)
```

The notification is an object and it will have an regid field which provides you the current mobile device id you can make use of that like **(posting to server, view in console.log(notification);)**

To send the device token to you server you need just do

```
var loginPost = {
                    "UserName":"Mike",
                    "PassWord":"xxxxxx",
                    "DeviceID":notification.regid
                  };
```

Using this loginPost variable object post to the server.

Comment: what is "senderID": "replace_with_sender_id"

Comment: @monoj rejinthala that is your project number which you have created in google cloud should be your senderId

Comment: if i want just device token should i need to clone the google cloud and follow the remaining steps or just register the app

Comment: to send a push notification ofcourse you need device token but it is not manditory to clone with GCM but you should clone project number and your server key to your current project.

Comment: i don't have any notification yet just i need to send device token when user login into the application that sit.i need to get device token with out any notification.