# User's devices tokens list are not showing in apps.ionic.io dashboard

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am working with sending push notification to android devices [Ionic].

Now started push notification with the help of the below reference url.

```
- https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/
```

This above url guide me to sent push notification to particular device token by using "Postman CURL request". I hereby attached some image url for your better understanding.

- http://postimg.org/image/qgqd22l4b/
- http://postimg.org/image/sp9lgiyjv/

I already tried push notification to list of users when it is in "alpha mode", which shows all device tokens.

In previous alpha mode, device tokens were only saved if we added them to a user, or sent raw tokens to the Push API.

Now in "Beta version", Here I am not able to detect any device tokens list. I need to call saveToken which will save the token and automatically tie it to the currently authenticated User.

```
var push = new Ionic.Push();
push.register(function(token) {
  push.saveToken(token);
});
```

Query:

```
- How can I get device tokens of users in apps.ionic.io dashboard?
```

Any one can explain clearly would be helpful to me. Thanks in advance!.

Comment: to get device toke follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717556/retrieve-the-device-token-from-device-using-ionic-framework/36717874#36717874

Comment: How to get token inside the ionic.apps.io dashboard under user's section?.

Comment: in ionic.io  website you dont need device token to send a push notification follow this tutorial https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications/

Comment: Did you note that the above link was outdated(That was an alpha version tutorial)

Comment: oh k but I did the push notification with out ionic.apps.io