# Push Notification using GCM for andorid in ionic full example

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

How to develop push notification for android in IONIC?
Please give me working example code.

Here is my code.

file name is app.js

```
 .config(['$ionicAppProvider', function($ionicAppProvider)
 {
   $ionicAppProvider.identify({
                        app_id: 'APP_ID,
                        api_key: 'PUBLIC_KEY'
                        });
  }])

.controller('PushCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicUser, $ionicPush)
{ 
 $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:tokenReceived', function(event, data)
 {  
   alert("Successfully registered token " + data.token);
   console.log('Ionic Push: Got token ', data.token, data.platform);   
   $scope.token = data.token;});

   $scope.identifyUser = function()
   {
      var user = $ionicUser.get();
      if(!user.user_id)
      {
        // Set your user_id here, or generate a random one.
        user.user_id = $ionicUser.generateGUID();
      };

// Metadata
angular.extend(user, {
    name: 'Simon',
    bio: 'Author of Devdactic'
});

  // Identify your user with the Ionic User Service
  $ionicUser.identify(user).then(function()
  {
      $scope.identified = true;
      console.log('Identified user'+user.name+'\n ID'+user.user_id);
   });
};
```

// Registers a device for push notifications

```
$scope.pushRegister = function()
{
  console.log('Ionic Push: Registering user');
 // Register with the Ionic Push service.  All parameters are optional.
 $ionicPush.register({
  canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
  canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
  canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
  canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
  onNotification: function(notification)
 {
    return true;
 }
});
};
});
```

Can you please tell where I am wrong. I got the error on this line

```
 <script src="lib/angular-websocket/angular-websocket.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you referred [this document](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push) ?

Comment: Refer [this](https://thinkster.io/ionic-push-notifications-tutorial) also...

Answer (score 0):

check this ng-cordova push notification plugin

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

check my stack answer how to get the device token

[Retrieve device token from device, using ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717556/retrieve-the-device-token-from-device-using-ionic-framework/36717874#36717874)

check here for the full demo blog with clear explaination 
https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications/

Comment: I already try this solutions but it didn't worked for me. If you have any-other solution please let me know. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I have followed the above tutorial and still now in my project it is working may i know what you have tried and give me some of your code so that can help you

Comment: where is your **.run** method

Comment: angular-websocket.js is an error becouse you have no such file in the lib folder. if you are going to use websocket then please install one

Comment: I already installed angular-websocket and I also wrote .run method