# How to fetch IOS device token using ionic?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

Ionic version 2.0
Cordova version 6.3.1
Xcode 8

Have already tried these two links but it did not help.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample

Looking for a detailed tutorial/material for fetching device token of IOS using ionic.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717556/retrieve-the-device-token-from-device-using-ionic-framework

Comment: you can use global variable "device" to access property like device id and other.
device.uuid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with Ionic push notification you must be having recent Ionic version released i.e. Ionic version 2, if you have older version (lower than Ionic version 1) it will not work.

The CordovaPush,CordovaPush v5 are already deprecated so don't use them.

For detailed understanding of push notification in Ionic 2 please refer this [ionic 2 push](http://nishanthkabra.com/ionic2push.html)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use this [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

```
if ( device.platform == 'iOS'){
pushNotification.register(
        tokenHandler,
        errorHandler,
        {
            "badge":"true",
            "sound":"true",
            "alert":"true",
            "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
        });
    }
}
```

Write this after the device ready event.

```
function errorHandler(error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

This is the error callback function.

```
function tokenHandler(result){
    // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
    // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
    //alert('device token = ' + result);
    sDeviceId = result ;
}
```

Here in sDeviceId you can get your device token.

Comment: the function errorHandler or tokenHandler are not being triggered when i run the code on device

Comment: In fact the control is not entering inside "pushNotification.register( "   itself.

Comment: Any errors ?? 
Have you configure your ios certificate properly to receive push notification ?
Don't check on simulator, check it on device.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in xcode console ... nothing is being processed after pushNotification.register( .... And I have also enabled xcode push notification without any error

Answer (score 1):

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

Try this only

I also faced the same problem.

Kindly check the IOS OS version of test device. If it is 10.0 or above please do

appropriate changes in Xcode settings in capabilties section

Allow push notification ( it should be checked).

PFB:

[Push Notification is not working on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489182/push-notification-is-not-working-on-ios-10)

Comment: ios version is not 10 or above it's only 8... if I use the same code control will not come inside this at all  "document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){   " t(http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/)  so I'm not able to get the device token .....so could you please suggest what can be done..

Comment: There is no need to call the register function inside device ready.

Comment: There is no need of register a device inside   device ready function

Comment: you can call register function externall at your will  ....

preferably in parent controller of your app

please try calling once outside the device ready function and let me know the results

Comment: then should i add only this


$cordovaPush.register(iosConfig).then(function(deviceToken) {// Success -- send deviceToken to server, and store for future useconsole.log("deviceToken: " + deviceToken)$http.post("http://server.co/", {user: "Bob", tokenID: deviceToken})}, function(err) {alert("Registration error: " + err)});

Comment: Hmm correct .. get the token and store it for future use

Comment: even with that i'm getting these errors 1. Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaPushProvider <- $cordovaPush(…) 2.Uncaught ReferenceError: $cordovaPush is not defined(…) ... I have added the plugin cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git still I'm facing that issue .

Comment: Please update your push plugin with update command . Sometimes config.xml file does not get updated as per newly installed plugin.

Comment: It that doesn't work , remove the push plugin through Cordova command and try readding it. Hope fully it will be resolved.